# Xcode 13.3 unit tests breaking with NSPredicate

Tags: xcode, xctest

My unit tests were working fine in Xcode 13.2.

I upgraded my Xcode to 13.3 and now some of my unit tests fail. Even an empty test case is breaking. This leads me to believe something internal in 13.3 has updated something.

Note: I don't have any usage of `NSPredicate` in my codebase.

Crash:

[image: screenshot of crash log]

Error log:

> 2022-03-22 10:01:59.109894-0700 xctest[68458:1354303] [general] NSPredicate: Use of NSFunctionExpression with instance of 'NSBundle' is forbidden.
> dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/{me}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app_name}-fgvbgpssjjxufdcidapunqbvyado/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOs

Comment: I have same issue here :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this too, but adding a test host fixed it for me, even an empty one.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Adding a test host to my unit tests that were failing passes now.